# How to hold posts and accounts for moderation on WordPress Network site

Tags: multisite, permissions, network-admin

In WordPress MU is there a way for a network admin to hold posts in moderation?

For example:

1. A user creates an account and a site
2. They create their first post
3. The post is held in moderation and the network admin receives an email
4. The network admin approves the post and / or the account
5. The user can now see the post or can create future posts

I think other sites like Discourse have this feature where the user is granted more permissions either over time or from a network administrator.

Answer (score 0):

All requirements in a single plugin is not available, either you have customize it or you have to these plugins and on top of this have to do small changes in those plugins.

Use this plugin for the post approval:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/publish-approval/
For User approval:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/